# 2 images on top of eachother one beneath runs function

Tags: jquery, css

I have two images positioned of the top of each other. When I click on the top image it calls the bottom images function.

```
$("#topImage").click(function(){
       alert("Top image clicked");

    });

$("#bottomImage").click(function(){
       alert("Bottom image clicked");

    });
```

Here when I click on `#topImage` it goes  `alert("Bottom image clicked");`

Comment: Hi, I got it sorted by swapping their z-index when appropriate. Thanks

Comment: saweet, made this for you anyways working fine :) http://jsfiddle.net/DQHgg/5/ have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: @weltraumpirat will do that. It won't let me accept my own answer for 2 more days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by swapping their z-index property's at the appropriate times.